# Import Data from Multiple Files using Import Tool

Tags: matlab

I want to import Multiple Files (waveforms in .wf format) using the Import Tool in MATLAB 2016a.

This is my (auto-generated) function

```
function Ring607062016175832 = importfile(filename, startRow, endRow)
%IMPORTFILE Import numeric data from a text file as a matrix.

%   RING607062016175832 = IMPORTFILE(FILENAME) Reads data from text file
%   FILENAME for the default selection.
%

%   RING607062016175832 = IMPORTFILE(FILENAME, STARTROW, ENDROW) Reads data
%   from rows STARTROW through ENDROW of text file FILENAME.
%
% Example:
%   Ring607062016175832 = importfile('Ring6_07-06-2016_17-58-32.wf', 1, 50001);
%
%    See also TEXTSCAN.

% Auto-generated by MATLAB on 2016/10/12 13:02:36

%% Initialize variables.
delimiter = ';';
if nargin<=2
    startRow = 1;
    endRow = inf;
end

%% Format string for each line of text:
%   column1: double (%f)
%   column2: double (%f)
% For more information, see the TEXTSCAN documentation.
formatSpec = '%f%f%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

%% Read columns of data according to format string.
% This call is based on the structure of the file used to generate this
% code. If an error occurs for a different file, try regenerating the code
% from the Import Tool.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(1)-startRow(1)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN,'HeaderLines', startRow(1)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
for block=2:length(startRow)
    frewind(fileID);
    dataArrayBlock = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(block)-startRow(block)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN,'HeaderLines', startRow(block)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
    for col=1:length(dataArray)
        dataArray{col} = [dataArray{col};dataArrayBlock{col}];
    end
end

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Post processing for unimportable data.
% No unimportable data rules were applied during the import, so no post
% processing code is included. To generate code which works for
% unimportable data, select unimportable cells in a file and regenerate the
% script.

%% Create output variable
Ring607062016175832 = table(dataArray{1:end-1}, 'VariableNames', {'VarName1','VarName2'});
```

When I run the function with input arguments such as

```
importfile('Ring6_07-06-2016_17-58-32.wf', 1, 50001)
```

I get the valid result for one imported file.

**My problem:**

I want to create a "for" loop to import the data from all ".wf" files.
Using this [example](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-data-interactively.html#btiwjhv) I created this "for" loop in a separate script:

```
numFiles = 361;
startRow = 1;
endRow = 50001;
WaveformData = cell(1,numFiles);

for fileNum = 1:numFiles
    filename = sprintf('Ring6%02d.wf',fileNum);
    WaveformData{fileNum} = importfile('filename', 1, 50001);
end
```

But when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in importfile (line 36)
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(1)-startRow(1)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'EmptyValue'
,NaN,'HeaderLines', startRow(1)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);

Error in Schleife (line 8)
    WaveformData{fileNum} = importfile(filename, startRow, endRow);
```

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong or give me a hint how to create a working "for"-loop to import all the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 WaveformData{fileNum} = importfile('filename', 1, 50001);
```

to

```
 WaveformData{fileNum} = importfile(filename, 1, 50001);
```

without the ' '

Comment: Well, it seems your file cannot be opened. Are you sure you construct valid file names (print them by removing the `;` of the filename=... line in your loop). You also need to be in the correct directory and the files need readable access in general. If you get the exact same message when following my answer, this proves my point that the file cannot be found / opened...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing the ; is something I should have used way earlier. I will try to generate a loop that imports all files that contain the ".wf" ending.